# JavaScript getting constructor is undefined

Tags: javascript, namespaces

this is my code:

```
window.myApp= window.myApp|| {};

myApp.jira = (function () {

  var getId = function () {
     return ...;
  }

  var init = function() {
     var id = myApp.jira.getId();
  }

})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    myApp.jira.init();  // here jira is null and getting undefined
});
```

when the page is loaded it says jira is undefined.

Comment: add `return init` at the end of the function

Comment: @bhb - `return init;` will not fix it entirely. It would require different syntax later: `myApp.jira()`. Or, as in my answer: `return { init: init }` and rest same as in original code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.myApp= window.myApp|| {};

// Function here is being immediately invoked. No "return" statement
// in your code is equivalent to "return undefined;".
myApp.jira = (function () {

  var getId = function () {
     return ...;
  }

  var init = function() {
     var id = myApp.jira.getId();
     // Bonus note: you can simplify this:
     // var id = getId();
  }

  // If we return an object with functions we want
  // to expose (to be public), it'll work,
  return {
    init: init,
    getId: getId
  };

})();  // <-- here you'll invoking this function, so you need return.

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Without 'return' above, myApp.jira evaluated to undefined.
    myApp.jira.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gyR4p/)

Or you can use `object literal` pattern instead:

```
var myApp = {};

myApp.jira = {

      getId: function () {
         return ...;
      },

      init: function() {
         var id = this.getId();
      }
    };
```